# JqueryMobile animation not looping while call to cordova.exec

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

so I have a button which when clicked call cordova more or less like this :

```
$(document).delegate("#update", "tap", A);

function A() {
  $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: "Please Wait...",
        textVisible: true,
        theme: "a"
    });
setTimeout(function () {B();}, 100);
}

function B () {
cordova.exec(function(success) {  
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, 
    function(error) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, 
    "MyPlugin",
    "MyAction",    [""]);
}
```

When I click on the button, it load the jQueryMobile animation but when the call to cordova is made, the animation stop looping and it gives the feeling the app crashed.
Everywhere I saw it says that call to plugin are asynchronous, but it does not looks like that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you implemented MyPlugin.java? What do the logs say?

Comment: Everything is working fine, except the animation is not looping. There is nothing in the log.